# Bit operations in Perl

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation

I have an attribute (32 bits-long), that each bit responsible to specific functionality. Perl script I'm writing should turn on 4th bit, but save previous definitions of other bits.

I use in my program:

```
Sub BitOperationOnAttr

{

my $a="";

MyGetFunc( $a);

$a |= 0x00000008;

MySetFunc( $a);

}
```

** MyGetFunc/ MySetFunc my own functions that know read/fix value.

Questions:

1. if usage of `$a |= 0x00000008;` is right ?
2. how extract hex value by Regular Expression from string I have : For example:

"Attribute: Somestring: value (8 long (0x8))"

Comment: Your questions are not related; they should be posted separately. That makes it easier for other people with similar questions to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. if usage of $a |= 0x00000008; is right ?

Yes, this is fine.

> 1. how extract hex value by Regular Expression from string I have : For example:
>
> "Attribute: Somestring: value (8 long (0x8))"

I'm assuming you have a string like the above, and want to use a regular expression to extract the "0x8". In that case, something like:

```
if ($string =~ m/0x([0-9a-fA-F]+)/) {
    $value = hex($1);
} else {
    # string didn't match
}
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. You show me the right way to solve the problem

Answer (score 25):

Perl provides several ways for dealing with binary data:

- The bitwise operators `&`, `|`, and `~`.
- The `pack` and `unpack` functions.
- The `vec` function.

Your scenario sounds like a set of packed flags. The bitwise operators are a good fit for this:

```
my $mask = 1 << 3;   # 0x0008
$value |=  $mask;    # set bit
$value &= ~$mask;    # clear bit
if ($value & $mask)  # check bit
```

`vec` is designed for use with bit vectors. (Each element has the same size, which must be a power of two.) It could work here as well:

```
vec($value, 3, 1) = 1;  # set bit
vec($value, 3, 1) = 0;  # clear bit
if (vec($value, 3, 1))  # check bit
```

`pack` and `unpack` are better suited for working with things like C structs or endianness.

Comment: I upvoted, but there is something very important missing: `vec` operates on a string! If we use a number; say: `$val=5; printf("b%08b",$val);` (this gives `b00000101`) -- then one can see that the "check bit" syntax, say: `for($ix=7;$ix>=0;$ix--) { print vec($val, $ix, 1); }; print "\n";` will not work (it gives `00110101`, which is not the same number). The correct is to convert the number to ASCII char, i.e. `print vec(sprintf("%c", $val), $ix, 1);`.